# Serialize C# object to JSON with constraint : Get old value if constraint is true

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

In my WEB API .NET core application, i have a route like that :

```
[Httput("{id}")]
api/task/{id}/content
```

The model "content" is C# class model with simple properties, but also with List or nested objects.

For exemple :

```
public class Content
{
    public string Reason{ get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public Description Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts{ get; set; }
}
```

I save this model in JSON format in my database ( because all this appears in a generic system).

Between controller and this JSON column in database, we do some treatment.

It's an Angular application which calls this API, the application can be in different working state, let's name it "STATE1", "STATE2", ...

when the angular application calls the api, I know what state context we are in.
What I want is:

I want to put a constraint on each property, which says "this property can only be updated in state X", we can secure on the angular side, but it is necessary to secure direct calls (like via postman)

if this property cannot be saved, i want to recover the property content of the previous object.

imagine something like this : ( i don't want this code, its just for understand the question )

```
    Something contentFromAngular = xx;
    Something currentContentFromDataBase = xx;
    if(STATE==STATE1)
    {
       contentFromAngular.Reason=currentContentFromDataBase.Reason
    }
    else If(STATE==STATE2)
    {
       contentFromAngular.Title=currentContentFromDataBase.PropA
       contentFromAngular.PropB=currentContentFromDataBase.PropB
    }
    ...
    SaveNewContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contentFromAngular)); //Save json in database after remove property "unauthorized"
```

I don't want a code like that, because if i have for example 20 STATE+ with dozens of properties, it's difficult to maintain.

i want something a little more generic.

My first idea its using on each of the properties custom attributes like :

```
   public class Content
{
    [UnAuthorizedState("STATE1")]
    public string Reason{ get; set; }
    [UnAuthorizedState("STATE2")]
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public Description Description { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts{ get; set; }
}
public class Contact
{
    [AuthorizedState("STATE5")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

But its very hard to set old value in reflection, because attribute is set on each sub class and not only on attribute on the "parent class"

So, i need your help for a solution.

Thank you

Comment: To be able to give you a more sensible answer I would suggest you use a more sensible example in your question. Names like `Something`, `PropertyA` and `PropertyB` makes it difficult to figure out what the essence of your goal is. Also, your `if...else if..` snippet seems opposite to what you're trying to do - in the result of `STATE1` from that snippet, the `PropA` **has not** changed in the database, but everything else has changed.

Comment: You should separate the serialization/deserialization process from your logic.

Comment: sorry, i edited my post, i hope its better